# My Site Speed is showing unavailable in google page speed

Tags: google-pagespeed, chrome-ux-report

I have experienced a Site Speed of currently showing Unavailable in Google Page Speed. It is showing that the data depends upon CrUX. Please make me understand why it is unavailable and what is CrUX

Comment: I have edited the description and topic.Please see if you understand or not What I am asking

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google released an update to Pagespeed insights recently, bumping it from version 2 to version 4. (https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/release_notes)

The new version includes data from the Chrome User Experience Report (CRUX), which is the speed score. You can see how that is calculated here:

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-user-experience-report/

On my two sites I have tested, the speed score is unavailable. For a large site like the BBC, there is a score available:

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bbc.co.uk

I'm guessing that the new site speed score is either rolling out gradually, or requires a certain volume of visitors to activate.

The old optimisation score is still there, but seems to be giving slightly different results for my sites, presumably they have updated a few of their testing metrics to reflect advances in web technologies, although that is just speculation on my part.

Comment: Yes, I have observed the changes made by Google and also the CRUX also implemented by them which tells about First Contentful Paint (FCP) and DOMContentLoaded (DCL). For More info https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/about Thanks again for explaining

Comment: So how can we get the page speed from Google Insight now?